# Dúvida em código em C!

Tags: c, input-output

Pessoal alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão da minha lista de exercicio:

Faça um programa que receba um número real, encontre e mostre:

- a) a parte inteira desse número;
- b) a parte fracionária desse número;
- c) o arredondamento desse número.

Não sei como calculo isso, meu professor mandou utilizar o **modf**, mas não funcionou, dando uma busca na web encontrei o seguinte código que ao testá-lo rodou perfeitamente, mas eu não consigo entender a logica que foi utilizada.

```
float numero,inteira,fracao,arred;
printf("Digite um numero real: ");
scanf("%f%*c",&numero);
printf("Parte Inteira : %d \n",(int) numero);
printf("Parte Decimal : %f", numero - ((int)numero));
```

Comment: C não é C# e não é C++.

Comment: a dúvida é sobre como fazer ou o que o algoritmo que você encontrou faz?

Comment: Como fazer,eu não entendi como o codigo  funciona

Answer (score 1):

Colocar (int) antes de uma variável retorna somente a parte inteira do numero (sem arredonda-lo), assim no segundo print ele mostrou somente a parte inteira, dessa forma que expliquei, no terceiro printf subtraiu a somente a parte inteira do numero com ponto flutuante, sobrando somente a parte decimal, e para o quarto printf que seria relativo ao arredondamento você poderia utilizar a função round(variavelFloat), que arredonda a variável.

O código ficaria assim:

```
{
    float numero,inteira,fracao,arred;
    printf("Digite um numero real: ");
    scanf("%f%*c",&numero);
    printf("Parte Inteira : %d \n",(int) numero);
    printf("Parte Decimal : %f", numero - ((int)numero));
    printf("Arredondado : %d", (int)round(numero));
}
```

Comment: Era isso que não tinha entendido,muito obrigado cara vc me salvou kk

Comment: `floor` não vai arredondar o número do jeito desejado. `floor` vai truncar o número. É a operação `piso` da matemática: vai arredondar para o inteiro mais baixo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado há controvérsias :) Tem maneiras diferentes de fazer o  floor . Claro, sempre pegará o piso, mas a definição do que é o piso pode mudar.